# Random matrix with non-identical variances

Tags: random-matrices

Hello,

Consider $A$ a $n \times n$ random matrix with centered Gaussian entries $A_{i,j}$ such that $$\mathbb{E}[A_{i,j}^2]=\sigma_j^2/n$$. The variances depend on the column only.

What do we know on the eigenvalues distribution ? In particular, if one assumes that $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_j^2 \to \bar{\sigma}^2$$ then is it true that :

$\rho(A):=max(|\lambda_k|) \to \bar{\sigma}^2$ when $n\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law and the references listed there.

To my knowledge, nothing other than the IID case is known.

Answer (score 4):

Your matrix model can be written as the product of a standard gaussian matrix with a deterministic diagonal matrix.  As such, I believe that Theorem 4 of this paper of Bordenave: http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3087 should give the asymptotic empirical spectral distribution under some reasonable hypotheses on the variances.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you for your answer. In Bordenave's paper I found another interesting reference http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2499.pdf
which adress the case of a diagonal matrix with Cauchy distributed elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this answers your question exactly but there are some known bounds. For example, [Latala](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-05/S0002-9939-04-07800-1/home.html) provides the following *high probability bound* under the conditions of finite fourth moments for the matrix entries 
$$\|A\|_2 \leq C \left( \max_i \sqrt{\sum_j \mathbb{E}A_{ij}^2}+ \max_j \sqrt{\sum_i \mathbb{E}A_{ij}^2} + \sqrt[4]{\sum_{i,j}\mathbb{E}A_{ij}^4} \right).$$

It would also be worthwhile to check out some of the recent review papers. One is by 
Laszlo Erdos and another is by Terrence Tao.